# mixing conditions for processes $(X_n, n\in \mathbb{N})$?

Tags: mixing

I hope this is not off topic, but I'm working with a process $(X_n, n\in \mathbb{N})$ and there's a theorem I want to use that is valid for certain strong mixing processes.

The thing is, the usual definitions of mixing processes usually start off with a `let $(X_n, n\in \mathbb{Z})$...' etc. Is there any particular reason to require that the index set be $\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition?

For instance, strong mixing is defined in the following manner: first we set $\alpha(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}):=\sup \{\vert P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)\vert\; :\;A\in\mathscr{A},B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ for sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}$ of $\mathscr{F}$. Then we define, for $J\in\mathbb{Z}$, the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{F}^J:=\sigma(X_j,\;j\leq J)$ and $\mathscr{F}_J:=\sigma(X_j,\;j\geq J)$. Then we set, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\tilde{\alpha}(n):=\sup_{J\in\mathbb{Z}}\alpha(\mathscr{F}^J,\mathscr{F}_{J+n})$ and say that $(X_n)$ is strongly mixing iff $\tilde{\alpha}(n)\rightarrow 0$.

So here's my question: can we give a similar definition of strongly mixing for a process $(X_n,\;n\in\mathbb{N})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can. Actually R. Bradley defines them in his book *Introduction to Strong Mixing Conditions* as the mixing coefficients of the two-sided sequence $(\dots,0,\dots, 0,X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots)$ (that is, a sequence $(Y_k)_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ for which $Y_k=0$ if $k\leqslant -1$ and $y_k=X_k$ if $k$ is non-negative). This is the most common and natural definition.